# apply background-color to select box in mozilla

Tags: html, css

I want to apply background color to select box.my code apply background color to option as expected in chrome but not mozilla.I want to apply background color to mozilla select box as in chrome

[image: mozilla]

[image: chrome]

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/4hym3qf9/)

Comment: I just checked Mozilla and Firefox Developer browsers and it seems to work fine. Can you elaborate more?

Comment: plz check my updated post

Answer (score 0):

you may do like this,

```
select option {
background: #60258e;
color: #fff;
}
```

or you can use any plugins.

Comment: can you provide a fiddle